# TimerTask cant run on calling thread

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I have a timer that should randomly change a state. I need it to start and then to run again after a new random time. But I have a problem when I try to call a it, I tells me that it can not run on the thread with the error: "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()".

How could I avoyd this?

```
public class GameScreen extends Screen {
    public void startTimer(){

            scanTask = new TimerTask() {

                    public void run() {
                        random = new Random();
                        int randState= random.nextInt(3);
                        state = randState;  
                    }
            };

            int rand = random.nextInt(7);
            timer.schedule(scanTask, (rand + 4) * 1000);
        }


        public void stopScan(){

            if(scanTask!=null){
                scanTask.cancel();
            }

        }

    public GameScreen(Game game) {
            super(game);

            startTimer();
    }
}
```

Here is the error stack.

```
07-23 20:49:28.917: E/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
07-23 20:49:28.917: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
07-23 20:49:28.917: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.testApp.myApp.GameScreen.<init>(GameScreen.java:35)
07-23 20:49:28.917: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.testApp.myApp.GameScreen.MainMenuScreen.update(MainMenuScreen.java:26)
07-23 20:49:28.917: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.testApp.framework.implementation.AndroidFastRenderView.run(AndroidFastRenderView.java:41)
07-23 20:49:28.917: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `Handler` in your own class and this class does not extend `Looper`.

You can make your class extend `Looper` and call `prepare()` are advised.

However the need to have `Handlers` in custom classes is usually rare. Maybe you can just find and remove it

Anyway, it has nothing to do with `TimerTask`

Comment: Thats great! I left a handler from some earlier tries, didn't use it so didn't think it could effect anything like this! Thanks alot!!